# How to resolve Primary IP Blocked response error in postman client and get successful response for Cardstream payment gateway?

Tags: java, payment-gateway, postman

I am new to Integrate various payment Gateways.
I use CardStream as payment Gateway and create postman Client for its various operations. There is a operation as REFUND_SALE and below is my postman Client screenShot:[image: Request postman client screen shot]

when I send this request I get following response:
[image: Response Postman client screen shot]

as seen in ResponseMessage I get Primary IP Blocked error.

And I get responseStatus as 2 which indicates Card referred but expected responseStatus should 0 which indicates Successful / authorised transaction.
Please can anybody help me to get this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my answer.

To resolve this error I have discuss with Cardstream support team and they suggested me to whitelist the approved IP Addresses(Static IP address) within the MMS (Merchant Management System).

To whitelist the IP Addresses simply log-in to the MMS(Merchant Management System) of Cardstream, click under Preferences and under the section label 'Direct Integration' enter to appropriate IP Address/es.

And I done with whitelist IP Address and resolve my problem.